# svn check out using C# program

Tags: c#, svn, command-prompt

I am writing a small utility to execute svn commands using c# program

Here is the key line in my program

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", @"svn checkout C:\TestBuildDevelopment\Code");

As I assume, the above code should be able to do svn check out and download all the code to the local path mentioned above. But what's happening is that, the command prompt opens up with the default path of the c# project and does nothing.

If I run this svn command in command line it works fine. But when I run using C# it just pops up the command prompt without executing the svn checkout operation. Any idea on what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using [`svnsharp`](http://code.google.com/p/svnsharp/) instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet svnsharp is great!!! I downloaded the dll and good to go now. Thanks a lot. I should mark this as the best answer. Eventhough there are some acceptable answers below, this is the best answer. But how can I mark this as accepted.

Comment: This is very old... nowadays, there is also SharpSVN:
 https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net

Answer (score 9):

You don t have to run CMD.exe. CMD.exe ist just a program that calls other assemblies.
You can call svn.exe directly with your argument checkout ... (but isnt there a url missing?)

```
Process.Start("svn.exe", @"checkout C:\TestBuildDevelopment\Code");
```

you may also try this:

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "svn.exe";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.Arguments = "checkout ...";

proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
if(proc.Start()) {
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the parameter `/c`. Try:

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe", @"/c svn checkout C:\TestBuildDevelopment\Code");
```

The parameter `/c` means that the cmd should execute the command and exit.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon notes, svnsharp would be a good choice here; but IMO the problem is shelling cmd.exe, rather than the exe you actually want to run:

```
Process.Start(@"path\to\svn.exe", @"checkout ""C:\TestBuildDevelopment\Code""");
```

although a `ProcessStartInfo` would make it easier to set the working path etc.